# jquery css selector using input type Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I am trying to figure out why the below jquery code is causing an error

```
 var table = $(sender).closest("table")[0];
 var trk_begin_field = $(table).find('.myClass:input');
```

I am seeing the below DOM exception being thrown in Chrome debugger:

Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '[id='myTable'] .myClass:input' is not a valid selector."

It looks like there is an extra space between the id's closing bracket and the class name. Not sure how that is getting in there or if that is even the cause of the error.

Comment: Add your html too :)

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? That seems to work: http://jsbin.com/xujohe/1 (I also tried jQuery 2.x in case they dropped the `:input` pseudo-selector.)

Comment: create a fiddle to demonstrates the problem please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use

```
var trk_begin_field = $(table).find('.myClass').filter('input');
```

Comment: since the field is a <td> element you cannot use find() on it you need to use filter().

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar this looks like an (attempt to) answer to me. More clarification to it might be needed, but still...

Answer (score 1):

if you are trying to get input with specific class name within table, you can do as follownig:

```
 var table=$("table"); //cast your table here
  table.find("input.a").each(function(){
  $(this).val("triggered");
  //input.b will be skipped
 });
```

`jsfiddle sample` http://jsfiddle.net/84nucpxm/1/